# What is the difference between compare() and compareTo()?

Tags: java, compare, compareto

What is the difference between `compare()` and `compareTo()` methods in Java? Do those methods give the same answer?

Comment: Which compare Class methode you mean?

Comment: for detailed explanation of the uses of both compare() and compareTo(): http://sysdotoutdotprint.com/index.php/2017/03/28/comparable-vs-comparator/

Comment: @mel3kings Can you please update the link in your comment? It currently provides no information towards this question.

Answer (score 178, accepted):

From [JavaNotes](http://web.archive.org/web/20090126135350/http://leepoint.net/notes-java/data/expressions/22compareobjects.html):

- `a.compareTo(b)`:
  **Comparable interface :** Compares values and returns an int which tells if the values compare less than, equal, or greater than.
  If your class objects have a **natural order**, implement the `Comparable<T>` interface and define this method. All Java classes that have a natural ordering implement `Comparable<T>` - Example: `String`, [wrapper classes](http://www.javatpoint.com/wrapper-class-in-java), `BigInteger`
- `compare(a, b)`:
  **Comparator interface :**  Compares values of two objects. This is implemented as part of the `Comparator<T>` interface, and the **typical use is to define one or more small utility classes that implement this, to pass to methods such as `sort()` or for use by sorting data structures such as `TreeMap` and `TreeSet`**. You might want to create a Comparator object for the following:

  - **Multiple comparisons**. To provide several different ways to sort something. For example, you might want to sort a Person class by name, ID, age, height, ... You would define a Comparator for each of these to pass to the `sort()` method.
  - **System class** To provide comparison methods for classes that you have no control over. For example, you could define a Comparator for Strings that compared them by length.
  - **Strategy pattern** To implement a Strategy pattern, which is a situation where you want to represent an algorithm as an object that you can pass as a parameter, save in a data structure, etc.

If your class objects have one natural sorting order, you may not need compare().

---

Summary from http://www.digizol.com/2008/07/java-sorting-comparator-vs-comparable.html

**Comparable**
A comparable object is capable of comparing itself with another object.

**Comparator**
A comparator object is capable of comparing two different objects. The class is not comparing its instances, but some other class’s instances.

---

Use case contexts:

**Comparable interface**

The equals method and `==` and `!=` **operators** test for equality/inequality, but **do not provide a way to test for relative values**.
Some classes (eg, String and other classes with a natural ordering) implement the `Comparable<T>` interface, which defines a `compareTo()` method.
You will want to implement `Comparable<T>` in your class if you want to use it with `Collections.sort()` or `Arrays.sort()` methods.

**Defining a Comparator object**

You can create Comparators to **sort any arbitrary way for any class**.
For example, the `String` class defines the [`CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER` comparator](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.lang/StringCASEINSENSITIVEORDER.htm).

---

The difference between the two approaches can be linked to the notion of:
**Ordered Collection**:

When a Collection is ordered, it means you can iterate in the collection in a specific (not-random) order (a `Hashtable` is not ordered).

A Collection with a **natural order** is not just ordered, but **sorted**. Defining a natural order [can be difficult!](https://blog.codinghorror.com/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order/) (as in [natural String order](http://web.archive.org/web/20090310030619/http://weblogs.java.net/blog/skelvin/archive/2006/01/natural_string.html)).

---

Another difference, pointed out by [HaveAGuess](https://stackoverflow.com/users/57344/haveaguess) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420223/what-is-the-difference-between-compare-and-compareto/420240?noredirect=1#comment46816131_420240):

- `Comparable` is in the implementation and not visible from the interface, so when you sort you don't really know what is going to happen.
- `Comparator` gives you reassurance that the ordering will be well defined.

Comment: Since this answer is exhaustive, here's something that annoys me about Comparable you might like to add: It is in the implementation and not visible from the interface, so when you sort you dont really know what is going to happen. Using a comparator gives you reassurance that the ordering will be well defined

Comment: @HaveAGuess good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: objects have a natural order, what does natural order mean here? Is a string data member for eg name in employee class has natural order??

Comment: @NarendraJaggi See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumeration. An order which facilitates enumeration. "Natural" in the sense that a given well-ordering on the index set provides a unique way to list the next element given a partial enumeration

Comment: @VedantKekan Thank you. I have restored 2 links in this answer.

Answer (score 18):

**`compareTo()`** is from the [**`Comparable`**](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface.

**`compare()`** is from the [**`Comparator`**](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface.

Both methods do the same thing, but each interface is used in a slightly different context.

The [Comparable](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface is used to impose a natural ordering on the objects of the implementing class. The `compareTo()` method is called the natural comparison method. The [Comparator](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface is used to impose a total ordering on the objects of the implementing class. For more information, see the links for exactly when to use each interface.

Comment: can u give some examples?Both methods give same answers?

Comment: I don't know why 'Comparable' is for natural ordering? We can customize it, can't we?

Answer (score 14):

**Similarities:**

- Both are custom ways to compare two objects.
- Both return an `int` describing the relationship between two objects.

**Differences:**
The method `compare()` is a method that you are obligated to implement if you implement the [`Comparator`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface.  It allows you to pass two objects into the method and it returns an `int` describing their relationship.

```
Comparator comp = new MyComparator();
int result = comp.compare(object1, object2);
```

The method `compareTo()` is a method that you are obligated to implement if you implement the [`Comparable`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface.  It allows an object to be compared to objects of similar type.

```
String s = "hi";
int result = s.compareTo("bye");
```

**Summary:**
Basically, these are two different ways to compare references.

Answer (score 10):

The methods do not have to give the same answers. That depends on which objects/classes you call them.

If you are implementing your own classes which you know you want to compare at some stage, you may have them implement the Comparable interface and implement the compareTo() method accordingly.

If you are using some classes from an API which do not implement the Comparable interface, but you still want to compare them. I.e. for sorting. You may create your own class which implements the Comparator interface and in its compare() method you implement the logic.

Answer (score 6):

Using Comparator, we can have **n number of comparison logic written for a class**.

E.g.

For a Car Class

We can have a Comparator class to compare based on car model number. We can also have a Comparator class to compare based on car model year.

**Car Class**

```
public class Car  {

    int modelNo;

    int modelYear;

    public int getModelNo() {
        return modelNo;
    }

    public void setModelNo(int modelNo) {
        this.modelNo = modelNo;
    }

    public int getModelYear() {
        return modelYear;
    }

    public void setModelYear(int modelYear) {
        this.modelYear = modelYear;
    }

}
```

**Comparator #1 based on Model No**

```
public class CarModelNoCompartor implements Comparator<Car>{

    public int compare(Car o1, Car o2) {

        return o1.getModelNo() - o2.getModelNo();
    }

}
```

**Comparator #2 based on Model Year**

```
public class CarModelYearComparator implements Comparator<Car> {

    public int compare(Car o1, Car o2) {

        return o1.getModelYear() - o2.getModelYear();
    }

}
```

But this is not possible with the case of **Comparable** interface.

In case of Comparable interface, we can have **only one logic in compareTo() method**.

Answer (score 5):

**Comparable** interface contains a method called `compareTo(obj)` which takes only one argument and it compares itself with another instance or objects of the same class.

**Comparator** interface contains a method called `compare(obj1,obj2)` which takes two arguments and it compares the value of two objects from the same or different classes.

Answer (score 4):

```
compareTo(T object)
```

comes from the java.lang.Comparable interface, implemented to compare this object with another to give a negative int value for this object being less than, 0 for equals, or positive value for greater than the other. This is the more convenient compare method, but must be implemented in every class you want to compare.

```
compare(T obj1, T obj2)
```

comes from the java.util.Comparator interface, implemented in a separate class that compares another class's objects to give a negative int value for the first object being less than, 0 for equals, or positive value for greater than the second object. It is needed when you cannot make a class implement compareTo() because it is not modifiable. It is also used when you want different ways to compare objects, not just one (such as by name or age).

Answer (score 3):

The relationship of the object having this method and its collaborators is different.

`compareTo()` is a method of the interface [Comparable](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), so it is used to compare THIS instance to another one.

`compare()` is a method of the interface [Comparator](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html), so it is used to compare two different instances of another class with each other.

If you will, implementing `Comparable` means that instances of the class can be easily compared.
Implementing `Comparator` means, that instances are suited to compare different objects (of other classes).

Answer (score 2):

`compareTo()` is called on one object, to compare it to another object.
`compare()` is called on some object to compare two other objects.

The difference is where the logic that does actual comparison is defined.

Comment: Not what I'd call a fantastic answer, but I don't think it deserves a downvote.

Comment: Agreed, personally I reserve downvotes for wrong or misleading answers. This one is definitely correct.

Comment: So where are those 'friendly' people who downvoted me? This is my second correct answer that was downvoted because someone missed the point. Either the point of downvoting or the point of my answer. Life's so cruel.. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The main difference is in the use of the interfaces:

Comparable (which has compareTo()) requires the objects to be compared (in order to use a TreeMap, or to sort a list) to implement that interface. But what if the class does not implement Comparable and you can't change it because it's part of a 3rd party library? Then you have to implement a Comparator, which is a bit less convenient to use.

Answer (score 1):

One more point:

- `Comparable` is used to define a **default** ordering for objects within a class
- `Comparator` is used to define a **custom** ordering to be passed to a method.

[comparator-vs-comparable](https://www.baeldung.com/java-comparator-comparable#comparator-vs-comparable)

Answer (score 0):

When you want to sort a List which include the Object Foo, the Foo class has to implement the Comparable interface, because the sort methode of the List is using this methode.

When you want to write a Util class which compares two other classes you can implement the Comparator class.

Answer (score 0):

Employee Table
**Name, DoB, Salary**
Tomas , 2/10/1982, 300
Daniel , 3/11/1990, 400
Kwame , 2/10/1998, 520

The **Comparable** interface allows you to sort a
list of objects eg Employees with reference to one primary field – for
instance, you could sort by name or by salary with the **CompareTo()** method

```
emp1.getName().compareTo(emp2.getName())
```

A more flexible interface for such requirements is provided by
the **Comparator** interface, whose only method is **compare()**

```
public interface Comparator<Employee> {
 int compare(Employee obj1, Employee obj2);
}
```

Sample code

```
public class NameComparator implements Comparator<Employee> {

public int compare(Employee e1, Employee e2) {
     // some conditions here
        return e1.getName().compareTo(e2.getName()); // returns 1 since (T)omas > (D)an 
    return e1.getSalary().compareTo(e2.getSalary()); // returns -1 since 400 > 300
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

There is a technical aspect that should be emphasized, too. Say you need comparison behavior parameterization from a client class, and you are wondering whether to use `Comparable` or `Comparator` for a method like this:

```
class Pokemon {
    int healthPoints;
    int attackDamage;
    public void battle (Comparable<Pokemon> comparable, Pokemon opponent) {
        if (comparable.compareTo(opponent) > 0) { //comparable needs to, but cannot, access this.healthPoints for example
            System.out.println("battle won");
        } else {
            System.out.println("battle lost");
        }
    }
}
```

`comparable` would a lambda or an object, and there is no way for `comparable` to access the fields of `this` Pokemon. (In a lambda, `this` refers to the outer class instance in the lambda's scope, as defined in the program text.) So **this doesn't fly**, and we have to use a `Comparator` with two arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Use Comparable interface for sorting on the basis of more than one value like age,name,dept_name...
For one value use Comparator interface

Answer (score -2):

```
Important Answar
String name;
int roll;

public int compare(Object obj1,Object obj2) { // For Comparator interface
    return obj1.compareTo(obj1);
}

public int compareTo(Object obj1) { // For Comparable Interface
    return obj1.compareTo(obj);
}
```

Here in `return obj1.compareTo(obj1)` or `return obj1.compareTo(obj)` statement 
only take Object; primitive is not allowed.
For Example

```
name.compareTo(obj1.getName()) // Correct Statement.
```

But

```
roll.compareTo(obj1.getRoll()) 
// Wrong Statement Compile Time Error Because roll 
// is not an Object Type, it is primitive type.
```

name is String Object so it worked.
If you want to sort roll number of student than use below code.

```
public int compareTo(Object obj1) { // For Comparable Interface
    Student s = (Student) obj1;
    return rollno - s.getRollno();
}
```

or

```
public int compare(Object obj1,Object obj2) { // For Comparator interface
    Student s1 = (Student) obj1;
    Student s2 = (Student) obj2;
    return s1.getRollno() - s2.getRollno();
}
```