# JavaBeans Comparison

Tags: java, compare, javabeans

Does anyone know about a free open source library (utility class) which allows you to compare two instances of one Java bean and return a list/array of properties which values are different in those two instances? Please post a small sample.

Cheers
Tomas

Comment: There are some good answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/472626/how-to-generically-compare-entire-java-beans

Answer (score 8):

[BeanComparator](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.8.3/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanComparator.html) of Apache commons is what you are looking for.

**Update**. A simple example that compares JavaBeans with one property (comparation is made agains only one property, you should create as many BeanComparators as properties you want to match).

```
import org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanComparator;

public class TestBeanComparator
{
    public TestBeanComparator()
    {
    }

    public class TestBean
    {
        int value;

        public TestBean()
        {
        }

        public int getValue()
        {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(int value)
        {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TestBeanComparator tbc = new TestBeanComparator();

        tbc.go();
    }

    public void go()
    {
        TestBean tbs [] = new TestBean[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < tbs.length; i++)
        {
            tbs[i] = new TestBeanComparator.TestBean();
            tbs[i].setValue((int) (Math.random() * 10));

            System.out.println("TestBean["+i+"] = " + tbs[i].getValue());
        }

        BeanComparator bc = new BeanComparator("value");

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Value to match: " + tbs[0].getValue());
        for (int i = 1; i < tbs.length; i++)
        {
            if(bc.compare(tbs[i], tbs[0]) == 0)
            {
               System.out.println("Match found in bean "+ i); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After some tests one result is successful. This is the output:

```
TestBean[0] = 0
TestBean[1] = 4
TestBean[2] = 0
TestBean[3] = 2
TestBean[4] = 7
TestBean[5] = 3
TestBean[6] = 0
TestBean[7] = 3
TestBean[8] = 7
TestBean[9] = 3

Value to match: 0
Match found in bean 2
Match found in bean 6
```

Obviously increasing TestBean array size will increase the chances to get matches.

You need to import to your project the following jars: commons-logging-*version*.jar, commons-beanutils-*version*.jar, commons-beanutils-core-*version*.jar, commons-beanutils-bean-collections-*version*.jar, commons-collections-*version*.jar.

The files are included inside [commons-logging](http://commons.apache.org/logging/), [commons-beanutils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/) and [commons-collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/) APIs.

Comment: Doesn't seem to answer the question. BeanComparator compares two beans by a single property; the question is about comparing multiple fields at once.

Answer (score 6):

[**`BeanComparator`**](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/package-summary.html#bean-comparator) can be used for [**collection sorting**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420223#420240).
It is a `Comparator` implementation that compares beans based on a shared property value.

> `BeanComparators` are generic comparators that can act upon any Java Bean. With a good underlying bean reflection system, they can handle a bean with bean properties, arrays, collections, and maps.
>
> If we have a `java.util.List` of Java Beans of type `Person` —- where `Person` has an age that's an `Integer`, a name that's a String, and a country that's a Country bean (which itself has a String name) —- **we can sort it anyway we want with a `BeanComparator`**.
>
> [Some examples](http://www.builderau.com.au/program/java/soa/Java-tips-for-list-iteration-and-bean-comparisons/0,339024620,320273675,00.htm):

```
List people = ...; // list of Person objects

//sort by age
BeanComparator comp = new BeanComparator("age");
Collections.sort(list, comp);

//sort by name
BeanComparator comp = new BeanComparator("name");
Collections.sort(list, comp);

//sort by country name
BeanComparator comp = new BeanComparator("country.name");
Collections.sort(list, comp);
```

There is no need to write a `PersonComparator` with lots of property options to sort by . Instead, a single `BeanComparator` class takes care of it all.

---

You will find a [full example here](http://www.zdnetasia.com/techguide/java/0,39044898,39233374,00.htm), with the following scenario:

> If you were implementing a comparator to compare properties dynamically (e.g., think of sorting rows in a table on a Web page based on which column the customer selects), then you could put off building your comparator until you knew which property had been selected for sorting.
>
> This is where `BeanComparator` really shines. The massive amounts of code you'd normally write to implement this behavior are reduced to a few lines when you use `BeanComparator`.

Comment: Doesn't seem to answer the question. BeanComparator compares two beans by a single property; the question is about comparing multiple fields at once.

Comment: what if I have more than two beans containing Name,Age,Country Name, How would I compare it with BeanComparater ? Bcoz, BeanComparater is mostly used to compare two java beans... Is it possible to compare more than 2 java beans' properties ...

Comment: @samkitshah not sure: I haven't worked with it for the past 5 years (since this answers was written in 2009)