# How to sort ArrayList based on a variables value

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have one `ArrayList<Users> users_list;` and in users i have name, surname, age etc. I want to implement an sorting algorithm that will sort my arraylist based on users age. I searched a lot but found only for sorting arrays.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a custom `java.util.Comparator`:

```
public class UserComparator implements Comparator<User> {
    @Override
    public int compare(User u1, User u2) {
        return u1.getAge().compareTo(u2.getAge());
    }
}
```

And sort it like:

```
Collections.sort(users_list, new UserComparator());
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here. 
[JavaBeans Comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437093/javabeans-comparison).
The second answer seems to be more to the point.

I would suggest using http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/ComparatorUtils.html#naturalComparator()

as the comparator parameter of the BeanComparator.