# Position in array not allowed to be int

Tags: java

So i have this piece of code I am using to sort a huge list of unordered words. I have them saved as an array of type String and want to use the insertion method for sorting it as it is required on my course to understand this idea. The problem is i am storing the position of the word i am looking to sort as an int(called temp) and it is saying incompatible types. I understand words are not integers, but i have the code as the following:

```
      public static void insertionsort() 
{
    for (int outer = 1; outer < array.length; outer++)//Outer=next number to be sorted 
    { 
        int temp = array[outer]; //Stores it for later use
        int inner = outer; // inner used to track shifts 
        while (inner > 0 && array[inner - 1] >= temp) 
        {  
            array[inner] = array[inner - 1];// swaps the number
            inner--;// Decrements
        } //shift them all right until one is smaller 
        array[inner] = temp;//Now it will put the stored number into its ordered position. 
    }
}
```

I just can not figure it out! Any help is much appreciated and I bet it is something simple. Just so you know, this is a code snippet of a bigger program I am working on.

Comment: To be clear, can you add the array variables to your code sample?

Comment: You are trying to assign the array's value, which is a String type, to an int.  That makes no sense.  You need to declare temp as a string.

Comment: @Ari my array is over 50,000 words long. So I am not sure you want to see that.

Comment: @OldProgrammer I have tried that as it was my first idea, but then my operand in the while loop does not work and I need it this way I think.

Comment: Sorry. I am totally confused.  If you want to save the INDEX of an array elements, then use an int.  If you want to save the VALUE of the array elements, use a String,  You are mixing appled and oranges.

Comment: @OldProgrammer Ok my bad, sorry about that. I know the difference, but see i need that VALUE at the point in my array of elements because i need it for my while loop which will find the position to put the temp number. Is there any way to do this without needed the '>= temp' part?

Comment: So create two variables, each to be of the correct type, and to be used for the correct purpose.  I can't make that any clearer.  Sorry.

Comment: Just use int everywhere. For array as well. coz int temp = array[outer] doesn't make sense. Use 2 arrays in this case but it's a long shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said it yourself that you have an array of `String`s, so you can't assign the element (a `String`) to an `int`.

Declare anything that stores an element of the array to be a `String`, not an `int`:

```
String temp = array[outer];
```

This means that this comparison will not be legal:

```
array[inner - 1] >= temp
```

because `>=` is not valid on `Strings`.  Compare with the [`compareTo` method on `String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29):

```
array[inner - 1].compareTo(temp) >= 0
```

Comment: I have tried that but i need it to be an int for my while loop to work, unless I can get around that.

Comment: @user3004820 You can't compare `Strings` (or any other `Object`) with such a comparison operator.  Use `compareTo` as in my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks man, you got what I meant. I just could not for the life of me figure out what to do, I had ttried using .compareTo but I was using it in the wrong spot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if array is a String array i.e String[] then `array[outer];` would return a String at position `outer` not Integer

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with how you are comparing your Strings - because you are filling your array with objects (String) instead of primitive dataTypes you will need the ability to compare one string to another.

Take a look at the Comparable and Comparator Interfaces. I think this will solve your problem:

[Java : Comparable vs Comparator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108604/java-comparable-vs-comparator)