# Best way to sort a Set?

Tags: java, collections

i have a class representing cars:

```
public class Car implements Comparable<Car> {
    String name;
    int value;
    ...
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Car o) {
        return name.compareTo(o.name);
    }
}
```

and another class representing races:

```
public class Race {
    cars = new HashSet<Car>();
    ...
    public Collection<Car> sortByName() {
        List<Car> carList = new ArrayList<>(cars);
        Collections.sort(carList);
        return carList;
    }
}
```

Its my implementation to sorting the Set, i know there is a TreeSet but i dont know how to compare it by TreeSet instead of HashSet, because if i used TreeSet i couldnt find method comprator() in it, can anyone help me if im doing well or if not how to use TreeSet?

Comment: If your `Car` class doesn't override `hashCode` and `equals` methods, then usage of `HashSet` is meaningless and you should use `TreeSet` from the beginning which uses `compareTo` method from the references it holds.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "method comprator()" because there's no such thing in `HashSet` either.

Comment: Yes I'm sorry im tired already, if i my code but i just change the HashSet to TreeSet the code works, so its fine?

Comment: Yes, it will be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a snippet from the `TreeSet` [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html):

`A NavigableSet implementation based on a TreeMap. The elements are ordered using their natural ordering, or by a Comparator provided at set creation time, depending on which constructor is used.`

Natural ordering refers to the order that you enforced by making the `Car` class implement the `Comparable` interface. Just add your cars to the `TreeSet` instance and they will be sorted for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Comparator` instead of `Comparable` in `Car`. `Comparator` is external to the class it compares, whereas `Comparable` is internal to that class. A more detailed explanation is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4108764/1838970

Now, on to your question. Implement this Comparator:

```
public class CarComparatorByName implements Comparator<Car> {
    public int compare(Car o1, Car o2) {
        return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
    }
}
```

Now make a TreeSet using that `Comparator`:

```
Set<Car> cars = new TreeSet<Car>(new CarComparatorByName());
```

That `TreeSet` will now use the comparator you created.

Alternatively, as noted in the comments below, you could just keep `Car` as a `Comparable` and simply throw them into a `TreeSet` upon creation. That `TreeSet` will use the natural sort order defined in `Car implements Comparable`.

Comment: Note that `TreeSet` implements [`SortedSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) which states: *The elements are ordered using their [natural ordering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) [<- links to `Comparable`], or by a `Comparator` typically provided at sorted set creation time.*, which means you don't need an external `Comparator` unless you want to sort using a different algorithm.

Comment: Ah yes, you could use either. I would argue that "name" isn't a natural sort order for Cars, but I suppose it depends upon your application. If he keeps his Comparable, he can just throw his existing Set into a TreeSet and it'll be sorted.

Comment: Then this answer can be moved to a comment saying: *I don't think cars should be compared by name only*...