# Java using Comparator

Tags: java, comparator, comparable

I am implementing Comparator and Comparable in my class Employee to sort an arraylist. I am sorting on 2 parameters name and ID. While sorting with ID using Collections.sort(Employee ob1, Employee ob2) it doesn't work. I get the compilation error that the class is not declared abstact and i am not overriding compare(), although i am doing it as:

```
public int compare(Employee ob1, Employee ob2)
{
return ob1.id-ob2.id;
}
```

it works fine if i use

```
public int compare(Object ob1, Object ob2)
{
return ((Employee)ob1).id-((Employee)ob2).id;
}
```

My doubt is why does't the earlier one work since Employee is also an Object.
The same issue is with compareTo(Object ob) as well, While overriding why can't i use Employee directly and why do i need to use Object there and later need to cast it to Employee class.

Comment: How did you declare your comparator? As `Comparator` or `Comparator<Employee>`?

Comment: @tobias_k obviously `Comparator`

Answer (score 5):

Polymorphism, using Object, Object overrides a raw-type in [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare%28T,%20T%29). Using your class names doesn't match that signature. For a compile error when you mix up the signature use the template type.

```
public class Employee implements Comparator<Employee> {
  // ....
  @Override
  public int compare(Employee ob1, Employee ob2) {
    return ob1.id-ob2.id;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the exact methode the interface defines.
If you want to work directly with your Object use the <> generic syntax:

```
public class Employee implements Comparator<Employee> 
{
   @Override
   public int compare(Employee ob1, Employee ob2) 
   {
      return ob1.id - ob2.id;
   }

}
```

Make sure to use the @`Override` [Annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94361/when-do-you-use-javas-override-annotation-and-why). This will give you a compiler warning if you get the methode wrong (parameter, return values etc.)

When using `Comparable` you can use it like this:

```
public class Employee implements Comparable<Employee> 
{
   @Override
   public int compareTo(Employee e) 
   {
      //your compare code
   }
}
```

See also: [Comparable vs Comparator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108604/java-comparable-vs-comparator)