# Specifying correct comparator when using it in a concrete subclass while compare method is in an abstract class?

Tags: java

I'm having trouble with this one, while the code is really long I'll present a basic view of the hierarchy of all my classes.

Interface:

```
public interface Shape extends Comparable<Shape> {
```

Abstract class:

```
public abstract class AbstractShape implements Shape {
...
public int compareTo(Shape theOther) {
//code already written

public int compare(Shape s1, Shape s2) {
//code already written
```

Circle class

```
public class Circle extends AbstractShape {
```

Rectangle class

```
public class Rectangle extends AbstractShape {
```

And finally.. the driver class

```
public class project {
...
Collections.sort(theList, ???);
```

After creating a List of all the shapes I have in mind, I would like to sort them using the Collections.sort method. I know how to use simple operations of the Collections.sort method, but how exactly would I specify the statement above to use the specified comparator that's sitting in the abstract class? I thought about changing the hierarchy around but I'm restricted to this hierarchy set up as my instructor does not allow us to modify the method headers at all for this assignment.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It will use that compareTo method if you just call `sort(theLost)`, thats the whole idea of implementing the `Comparable` interface

Comment: What is the result of comparing a `Rectangle` with a `Circle`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class implements `Comparable` so you don't need to pass a `Comparator` object as second argument, just pass nothing:

```
Collections.sort(theList);
```

Comment: That was just a quick answer to unstuck you. For detailed explanations about appropriate use of `Comparable` & `Comparator` there are already a ton of existing Q&As, for example see [that one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4108764/6730571)

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is correct; but when you intend to use a Comparator, then you simple have to make it possible to provide an instance of that Comparator to the sort method.

In other words: instead of having AbstractShape implement Comparable, you would simply create something like

```
public class ShapeComparator implements Comparator<AbstractShape>
```

and then you have to pass some ShapeComparator object to the sort() call. You could even make that thing an enum with a single instance, then you do something like

```
sort(listOfShapes, ShapeComparator.INSTANCE);
```

Comment: That's a useful complement. Minor complement to that: usually comparators are stateless so it's safe to share a single instance, but it's on the implementor to guarantee that, it's not always the case. So, for a generic answer I'd show how to create a new instance.

Comment: I guess you mean `Shape` instead of `AbstractShape`?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your own comparator to the sort function:

```
Collections.sort(theList, (o1, o2) -> {
/*compare code*/ 
});
```

Hugues Moreau is right: you don't need comparator if your class already implements `Comparable`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use a Comparator but you make your class implement the Comparable interface. It is a different thing.

You need only    `public int compareTo(Shape shape);` method. Why do you declare also `public int compare(Shape s1, Shape s2)` in the AbstractClass.
It makes no sense.

As @Hugues Moreau suggested, you don't need to specify anything as you use Comparable instances that is an alternative to the Comparator use.

> After creating a List of all the shapes I have in mind, I would like
>   to sort them using the Collections.sort method
>
> know how to use simple operations of the Collections.sort method, but
>   how exactly would I specify the statement above to use the specified
>   comparator that's sitting in the abstract class? I

You should not compare pigs and monkeys in the `sort()` method.
The overriden `compareTo()` method will be applied at runtime.
As you want to use a specific `Comparator` and not the `Comparable` implementation that may differ between subclasses, sort them with a `Comparator`.
For example :

```
Collections.sort(theList, new MyAbstractShapeComparator());
```