# Implementing Comparable in Java

Tags: java, compare

So I'm trying to compare two shape's area using Comparable. I implement it in my class and I'm trying to override compare right now in my LineSegment class which extends my own abstract class Shape.

```
class LineSegment extends Shape implements Comparable{

public int compareTo(Object object1, Object object2)
      {
         LineSegment ls1 = (LineSegment) object1;
    LineSegment ls2 = this;
    return Double.compare(ls1.getArea(), ls2.getArea());
}



}
```

Before I had an issue with comparing two doubles and I saw a solution to the problem on here with that return statement and Double. getArea() returns a double area for the LineSegment. So I have ran into this error, any help would be appreciated, thanks- `LineSegment is not abstract and does not override abstract method compareTo(java.lang.Object) in java.lang.Comparable
class LineSegment extends Shape implements Comparable`

Comment: compareTo should have only one parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Comparator interface instead of Comparable. so your class definition will change to:

```
class LineSegment extends Shape implements Comparator <LineSegment> {
....//with compare(LineSegment ls1, LineSegment ls2) and you dont need typecasting
```

Or if you are intending to comparable then you need implementation like:

```
class LineSegment extends Shape implements Comparable<LineSegment>{
    public int getArea() {...}

    public int compareTo(LineSegment object1)
    {

        return Double.compare(this.getArea(), object1.getArea());
    }
}
```

Comment: @user4254704 Glad it worked for you. Please accept the answer if indeed it helped and closet his question.

Comment: how do you close a question?

Answer (score 1):

In order to implement `Comparable`, you need to implement `compareTo` method.

If you want to use Comparator, you should implement `compare`.

See more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420223/what-is-the-difference-between-compare-and-compareto)

Use:

```
class LineSegment extends Shape implements Comparable<LineSegment>{
...

    @Override
    public int compareTo(LineSegment other) {
        return Double.compare(this.getArea(), other.getArea());
    }

}
```

Comment: Right I need to use Comparable, I changed my code and still getting the same error

Comment: @user4254704 See answer above http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26948604/implementing-comparable-in-java/26948641#26948641

Comment: compareTo should get one argument only. see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T)

Answer (score 0):

With Comparable, you have to compare one object with this object:

```
public int compareTo(Object object1){
    LineSegment ls1 = (LineSegment) object1;
    LineSegment ls2 = this;
    return Double.compare(ls1.getArea(), ls2.getArea());
}
```

this is only rewrited, but you should use `<LineSegment>`:

```
class LineSegment extends Shape implements Comparable<LineSegment>{
    public int compareTo(LineSegment ls){
        return Double.compare(ls.getArea(),this.getArea());
    }
}
```