# Compare two objects with "<" or ">" operators in Java

Tags: java, object, operator-overloading, comparable

How to make two objects in Java comparable using "<" or ">"
e.g.

```
MyObject<String> obj1= new MyObject<String>(“blablabla”, 25);
MyObject<String> obj2= new MyObject<String>(“nannaanana”, 17);
if (obj1 > obj2) 
    do something.
```

I've made MyObject class header as

`public class MyObject<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparable<MyObject<T>>`
and created method Comp but all the gain I got is now I can use "sort" on the list of objects, but how can I compare two objects to each other directly? Is

```
if(obj1.compareTo(obj2) > 0)
     do something
```

the only way?

Comment: "Is
[`compareTo`]
the only way?" Yep.

Comment: You cannot overload `<` or `>` operators in Java.

Comment: In C# you can overload operators like that.

Comment: You can't compare with `>` & `<` because there might exist more than one variable in your object and Java won't know which variable you want to use for comparison. If you do not override the compareTo method, it will compare the string object in lexical order.

Comment: Well, `compareTo` isn't the _only_ way--you could define `isLessThan`, `isGreaterThan`, etc. methods if you want, that return `boolean`.  It's arguable that they'd be more readable than `compareTo`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77718/why-doesnt-java-offer-operator-overloading

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You cannot do operator overloading in Java. This means you are not able to define custom behaviors for operators such as `+`, `>`, `<`, `==`, etc. in your own classes.

As you already noted, implementing `Comparable` and using the `compareTo()` method is probably the way to go in this case.

Another option is to create a `Comparator` (see the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)), specially if it doesn't make sense for the class to implement `Comparable` or if you need to compare objects from the same class in different ways.

To improve the code readability you could use `compareTo()` together with custom methods that may look more natural. For example:

```
boolean isGreaterThan(MyObject<T> that) {
    return this.compareTo(that) > 0;
}

boolean isLessThan(MyObject<T> that) {
    return this.compareTo(that) < 0;
}
```

Then you could use them like this:

```
if (obj1.isGreaterThan(obj2)) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 4):

*I would advocated that readability must be a primer for us as developers.*

Apache Commons Lang (commons-lang) provides a simple fluent utility which reads a lot clearer:

```
if (is(obj1).greaterThan(obj2)) {
     // do something
}
```

Note: `is` is shorthand for `ComparableUtils.is` which can be imported the following this static import statement:

```
import static org.apache.commons.lang3.compare.ComparableUtils.is;
```

Comment: reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) A exist so that Object conforms to Comparable<A>

Answer (score 3):

Using [`Comparable.compareTo(T)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29) is the only option (or [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)). The interface only defines that one method (while `Comparator` adds `equals`), and it *compares this object with the specified object for order.* Further, Java does not permit operator overloading (so you won't be able to directly change the operand used for invoking that method; or in fact modify the interface).

Comment: There's also `Comparator`.

Comment: @Makoto [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) provides two methods (and still doesn't allow operator overloading), but that's a fair point in that it is technically another option.

Comment: I was merely looking at it from the "other option" angle. :)

Answer (score 3):

It is not the only way. You can implement a Comparator as well. Comparator uses `compare()` method as oppose to `Comparable` which uses `compareTo()` method.

The reason you can't use `>` or `<` to compare objects directly is because Java won't know which variable you want to use for the comparison (as there might exist more than one variable in the object).

In order to compare objects, those objects must be comparable. You need to define and tell Java how you want to compare them.

Java collection provides a `sort` method. However some school does give assignment of asking you to write you own sort methods which ultimately still uses the `compareTo()` for comparison.

You can take a look on the subtle differences between `Comparable` vs `Comparator` here: [What is the difference between compare() and compareTo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420223/what-is-the-difference-between-compare-and-compareto)

---

I think it is also worth mentioning that, by default Java compares String (objects) in a lexicographical order if you did not override the `compareTo()` method.