# how do i compare the value of an object

Tags: java, oop, linked-list

in this code i want to put integers in a double list 
and then to check if the list is sorted or not 
so in a method i try to compare the value the first 
object of the list with the second, then the second with the third etc.
what i dont remember/know is how you compare them

```
public class Ergasthrio6 {

    public static boolean isSorted(DoubleLinkedList dl) throws ListEmptyException{
        DoubleLinkedList selectedItem = (DoubleLinkedList) dl.removeFirst();
        dl.insertLast(selectedItem);
        DoubleLinkedList tmp;
        for (int i=1; i < dl.size(); i++){
            tmp = (DoubleLinkedList) dl.removeFirst();
            dl.insertLast(tmp);
            if (selectedItem < tmp)) <-----here
               return false; 
            else
               selectedItem = tmp;
            tmp = tmp.removeFirst();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ListEmptyException {
        // TODO code application logic here
        DoubleLinkedList dl = new DoubleLinkedList();
        for (int i=0; i < 10; i++)
            dl.insertFirst(UserInput.getInteger());
        isSorted(dl);
    }
}
```

Comment: compare as in integer comparision ? you're already doing it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare two objects with "<" or ">" operators in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29179194/compare-two-objects-with-or-operators-in-java)

Comment: It's not a duplicate, he is probably asking how to do dl[i] < d[i-1], it's related to algorithm.

Comment: If you post the source or available methods of DoubleLinkedList, that'll help in answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

an easy approach would be to create a method in which each variable of the two objects will be compared. returning a boolean or a -1, 1 kind of value would suffice in case of less than or not scenarios.