# How to Compare a List of Objects and Their Properties, then Update the Original List in Java

Tags: java, list, collections, comparison, delta

I have an object that has a list as its property, e.g.

```
public class A {
  private String aName;
  private List<B> bList;
}

public class B {
  private String bName;
}
```

Lets assume that we have two lists of `A`'s:

```
List<A> existingList = new ArrayList<A>();
// populate it with a list of A's which in turn, each has its own list of B's

List<A> newList = new ArrayList<A>();
// populate it with possibly some new A's and/or, an existing A which its property B has new items
```

With that in mind, I would like to know the fastest way to compare these two list of `A`'s, and add the delta of these two lists to the `existingList`.

Note that we are also comparing a list of `B`'s for `A`'s in both lists, so if there is a matching `A`'s, but there is a delta of their `B`'s, we should be able to add it to `existingList`'s `A`'s `bList`.

Equally, if we detect an item has been deleted from `newList`, we should remove that from `existingList`.

Note, this is not simply about comparing two objects, but rather finding the delta deep in the object graph and updating or adding new and/or existing parts. Here is the sample example:

```
package collection.delta.model;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

package collection.delta.model;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

import org.apache.commons.collections4.CollectionUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

public class A {
    private String aName;

    private List<B> bList;

    public String getaName() {
        return aName;
    }

    public void setaName(String aName) {
        this.aName = aName;
    }

    public List<B> getbList() {
        return bList;
    }

    public void setbList(List<B> bList) {
        this.bList = bList;
    }

    public A(String name, List<B> bList) {
        this.aName = name;
        this.bList = bList;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == null) {
            return false;
        }

        if (o == this) {
            return true;
        }

        if (!(o instanceof A)) {
            return false;
        }

        A b = (A) o;
        return StringUtils.isNotBlank(aName) && StringUtils.equalsAnyIgnoreCase(b.getaName(), aName)
                && CollectionUtils.disjunction(this.getbList(), b.getbList()).isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(aName)) {
            return 31;
        }

        return Objects.hashCode(aName);
    }   

package collection.delta.model;

import java.util.Objects;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

public class B {
    private String bName;

    public String getbName() {
        return bName;
    }

    public void setbName(String bName) {
        this.bName = bName;
    }

    public B(String name) {
        this.bName = name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == null) {
            return false;
        }

        if (o == this) {
            return true;
        }

        if (!(o instanceof B)) {
            return false;
        }

        B b = (B) o;
        return StringUtils.isNotBlank(bName) && StringUtils.equalsAnyIgnoreCase(b.getbName(), bName);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(bName)) {
            return 31;
        }

        return Objects.hashCode(bName);
    }
}

package collection.delta;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.apache.commons.collections4.CollectionUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

import collection.delta.model.A;
import collection.delta.model.B;

public class App {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        List<A> originalA = new ArrayList<A>();
        List<A> newA = new ArrayList<A>();

        List<B> bListOriginalA1 = new ArrayList<B>();
        bListOriginalA1.add(new B("originalA1_B1"));
        bListOriginalA1.add(new B("originalA1_B2"));
        bListOriginalA1.add(new B("originalA1_B3"));
        bListOriginalA1.add(new B("originalA1_B4"));

        A originalA1 = new A("originalA1", bListOriginalA1);

        List<B> bListOriginalA2 = new ArrayList<B>();
        bListOriginalA2.add(new B("originalA2_B1"));
        bListOriginalA2.add(new B("originalA2_B2"));
        bListOriginalA2.add(new B("originalA2_B3"));
        bListOriginalA2.add(new B("originalA2_B4"));

        A originalA2 = new A("originalA2", bListOriginalA2);

        List<B> bListOriginalA3 = new ArrayList<B>();
        bListOriginalA3.add(new B("originalA3_B1"));
        bListOriginalA3.add(new B("originalA3_B2"));
        bListOriginalA3.add(new B("originalA3_B3"));
        bListOriginalA3.add(new B("originalA3_B4"));

        A originalA3 = new A("originalA3", bListOriginalA3);

        originalA.add(originalA1);
        originalA.add(originalA2);
        originalA.add(originalA3);


        List<B> bListNewA1 = new ArrayList<B>();
        bListNewA1.add(new B("originalA1_B1"));
        bListNewA1.add(new B("originalA1_B2"));
        bListNewA1.add(new B("originalA1_B3"));
        bListNewA1.add(new B("originalA1_B4"));

        A newA1 = new A("originalA1", bListNewA1);

        List<B> bListNewA2 = new ArrayList<B>();
        bListNewA2.add(new B("originalA2_B1"));
        bListNewA2.add(new B("originalA2_B2"));
        bListNewA2.add(new B("originalA2_B3"));
        bListNewA2.add(new B("originalA2_B4"));

        A newA2 = new A("originalA2", bListNewA2);

        List<B> bListNewA3 = new ArrayList<B>();
        bListNewA3.add(new B("originalA3_B1"));
        bListNewA3.add(new B("originalA3_B2"));
        bListNewA3.add(new B("originalA3_B5"));
        bListNewA3.add(new B("originalA3_B4"));

        A newA3 = new A("originalA3", bListNewA3);

        List<B> bListNewA4 = new ArrayList<B>();
        bListNewA4.add(new B("A4_B1"));
        bListNewA4.add(new B("A4_B2"));
        bListNewA4.add(new B("A4_B3"));
        bListNewA4.add(new B("A4_B4"));

        A newA4 = new A("originalA4", bListNewA4);

        newA.add(newA1);
        newA.add(newA2);
        newA.add(newA3);
        newA.add(newA4);

        List<A> result = CollectionUtils.disjunction(originalA, newA).stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
        for (A a : newA) {
            for (A aResult : result) {
                if (StringUtils.equalsAnyIgnoreCase(a.getaName(), aResult.getaName())) {
                    originalA.add(aResult);
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("");
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare two objects with "<" or ">" operators in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29179194/compare-two-objects-with-or-operators-in-java)

Comment: @surendrapanday This question is not about only comparison of two objects. Please do not mark it as duplicate or down voted before understanding the problem.

Comment: Just letting you know that I have not downvoted you, but i found bunch of other questions related to this; someone else downvoted you, I don't know who did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
package collection.delta;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import collection.delta.model.A;
import collection.delta.model.B;

public class App {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        List<A> originalA = new ArrayList<A>();
        List<A> newA = new ArrayList<A>();

        List<B> bListOriginalA1 = new ArrayList<B>();
        bListOriginalA1.add(new B("originalA1_B1"));
        bListOriginalA1.add(new B("originalA1_B2"));
        bListOriginalA1.add(new B("originalA1_B3"));
        bListOriginalA1.add(new B("originalA1_B4"));

        A originalA1 = new A("originalA1", bListOriginalA1);

        List<B> bListOriginalA2 = new ArrayList<B>();
        bListOriginalA2.add(new B("originalA2_B1"));
        bListOriginalA2.add(new B("originalA2_B2"));
        bListOriginalA2.add(new B("originalA2_B3"));
        bListOriginalA2.add(new B("originalA2_B4"));

        A originalA2 = new A("originalA2", bListOriginalA2);

        List<B> bListOriginalA3 = new ArrayList<B>();
        bListOriginalA3.add(new B("originalA3_B1"));
        bListOriginalA3.add(new B("originalA3_B2"));
        bListOriginalA3.add(new B("originalA3_B3"));
        bListOriginalA3.add(new B("originalA3_B4"));

        A originalA3 = new A("originalA3", bListOriginalA3);

        originalA.add(originalA1);
        originalA.add(originalA2);
        originalA.add(originalA3);


        List<B> bListNewA1 = new ArrayList<B>();
        bListNewA1.add(new B("originalA1_B1"));
        bListNewA1.add(new B("originalA1_B2"));
        bListNewA1.add(new B("originalA1_B3"));
        bListNewA1.add(new B("originalA1_B4"));

        A newA1 = new A("originalA1", bListNewA1);

        List<B> bListNewA2 = new ArrayList<B>();
        bListNewA2.add(new B("originalA2_B1"));
        bListNewA2.add(new B("originalA2_B3"));
        bListNewA2.add(new B("originalA2_B4"));
        bListNewA2.add(new B("originalA2_B2"));

        A newA2 = new A("originalA2", bListNewA2);

        List<B> bListNewA3 = new ArrayList<B>();
        bListNewA3.add(new B("originalA3_B1"));
        bListNewA3.add(new B("originalA3_B2"));
        bListNewA3.add(new B("originalA3_B5"));
        bListNewA3.add(new B("originalA3_B4"));

        A newA3 = new A("originalA3", bListNewA3);

        List<B> bListNewA4 = new ArrayList<B>();
        bListNewA4.add(new B("A4_B1"));
        bListNewA4.add(new B("A4_B2"));
        bListNewA4.add(new B("A4_B3"));
        bListNewA4.add(new B("A4_B4"));

        A newA4 = new A("originalA4", bListNewA4);

        newA.add(newA1);
        newA.add(newA2);
        newA.add(newA3);
        newA.add(newA4);

        List<A> result = newA.stream()
                .filter(not(new HashSet<A>(originalA)::contains))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        A tempA = null;
        B tempB = null;
        List<B> bList = null;
        for (A a : result) {
            if (!containsName(originalA, a.getaName())) {
                originalA.add(a);
            } else {
                tempA = getAIfPresent(originalA, a.getaName());

                if (tempA != null) {

                    bList = a.getbList().stream()
                            .filter(not(new HashSet<B>(tempA.getbList())::contains))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());

                    if (bList != null) {
                        tempA.getbList().addAll(bList);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("");
    }

    public static <T> Predicate<T> not(Predicate<T> predicate) {
        return predicate.negate();
    }

    public static boolean containsName(final List<A> list, final String name){
        return list.stream().map(A::getaName).filter(name::equals).findFirst().isPresent();
    }

    public static A getAIfPresent(final List<A> list, final String name) {
        return list.stream().filter(x -> x.getaName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)).findFirst().orElse(null);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Implement `equals()` and `hashCode` for both classes.

Step 2: Convert lists to sets.

Step 3: Use one or more of the [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) methods `addAll`, `removeAll`, and/or `retainAll` to exercise set operations such as union, intersection, and difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you care about order, then just use the equals method:

```
list1.equals(list2);
```

From the javadoc:

> Compares the specified object with this list for equality. Returns
>   true if and only if the specified object is also a list, both lists
>   have the same size, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two
>   lists are equal. (Two elements e1 and e2 are equal if (e1==null ?
>   e2==null : e1.equals(e2)).) In other words, two lists are defined to
>   be equal if they contain the same elements in the same order. This
>   definition ensures that the equals method works properly across
>   different implementations of the List interface.

If you want to check independent of order, you could copy all of the elements to Sets and use equals on the resulting Sets:

```
public static <T> boolean listEqualsIgnoreOrder(List<T> list1, List<T> list2) {
    return new HashSet<>(list1).equals(new HashSet<>(list2));
}
```

A limitation of this approach is that it not only ignores order, but also frequency of duplicate elements. For example, if list1 was ["A", "B", "A"] and list2 was ["A", "B", "B"] the Set approach would consider them to be equal.

If you need to be insensitive to order but sensitive to the frequency of duplicates you can either:

sort both lists (or copies) before comparing them
or copy all elements to a Multiset.