# intro programming on java with compareTo

Tags: java

just got some computer science from my friend,  I believe it is a intro to programming assignment, and I was trying on it, but it seems there are so many issue, seems I am majoring CS, can someone help me on those questions step by step, would be appreciated.  in instructions are following:

Create  a   public  class   Movie with  private instance    variables   String title
and int year. The   class   should  declare that    it  implements  the 
Comparable interface,    and should  provide the following:

• A constructor that    takes   2   arguments:  a   String  and an  int (in that    order)
for initializing    title and   year.

• A method  that    satisfies   the Comparable interface.    Movies  should  be  compared    first   by  title   and then    by  year.

{ The   Maltese Falcon  1941,               The Thomas  Crown   Affair  1968,           The Thomas  Crown   Affair 1999}

An  equals()    method  that    is  compatible  with    the method  that    satisfies   the 
Comparable interface.

• A toString()  method  that    prints  “Movie” followed    by  1   space   followed    by
the title   followed    by  1   space   followed    by  open-parenthesis    followed    by
the year    followed    by  close-parenthesis.  Example:
                                                                                                                                                            The Maltese Falcon  (1941)

• A public  static method   getTestMovies(),    which   returns an  array   of  10
unique  Movie   instances.  The 0th and 1st array   elements    must    be 2    movies
with    the same    title   but from    different   years   (e.g.   The Thomas  Crown
Affair  1968    and The Thomas  Crown   Affair  1999,   or  True    Grit    1969    and 
True    Grit    2010).  The 2nd and 3rd elements must   2   movies  with    different
titles  but from    the same    year    (e.g.   The Martian 2015    and Bridge  of  Spies
2015).  The 4th and 5th elements    must    be  2   different   objects that
represent   the same    movie.

• A hashCode()  method. Use the following:

```
public int hashCode()
{
return title.hashCode() + year;
 }
```

the following is what I have so far, I have the constructor and the starter, but I am sure how to do it.

```
public class Movie implements Comparable<Movie>{
private String title;
private int year;

public Movie(String title, int year){
    this.title = title;
    this.year = year;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Movie that) {
    int value = 0;
    if(this.title == that.title)
    {
        if(this.year < that.year){
            value = 0;
        }
        else{
            value = -1;
        }
    }
    return value;
}

public static void getTestMovie(){

}

public boolean equals(Object x)
{
```

}
}

Any Helps are appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

When you want sorting other than natural order, you should Comparator rather than Comparable. Please follow below link for more info :
[What is the difference between compare() and compareTo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420223/what-is-the-difference-between-compare-and-compareto)

Regarding string comparison use str1.equals(str2). For the reason follow below link :
[What is the difference between == vs equals() in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-vs-equals-in-java)

For rest of the questions, please post some tried code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `this.title == that.title` on Strings. You should use `this.title.equals(that.title)`.

**Except**, for this code, you shouldn't. You should use `this.title.compareTo(that.title)`.

If that return non-zero, return that value, because it represents the ordering when titles differ.

If it returned zero, the titles were equal, and you need the secondary check on year. For that use `Integer.compare(this.year, that.year)`.