# Collections.sort() works with Comparable or Comparator?

Tags: java, generics

What exactly does the following overload of `Collections.sort()`:

> `sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)`

ask for as the second argument?

---

Example: I initiate a list of 7 random integers as:

```
List<Integer> listOfInts = new ArrayList<>();
Random rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    listOfInts.add(rand.nextInt());
}
```

Then I try to sort them using `Collections.sort()` as:

```
Collections.sort(listOfInts, Integer :: compare);
```

as well as:

```
Collections.sort(listOfInts, Integer :: compareTo);
```

and they both work. **Why doesn't the call to sort the collection using `compareTo()` throw/fail?** The signature of `compareTo()` is totally different from the signature of `compare()`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/420223/what-is-the-difference-between-compare-and-compareto

Comment: I think you are getting slightly confused by lambdas introduced in Java 8. Try that in Java 7 and you will be able to easily see it.

Comment: @msadler: Methods giving same answer is different from methods being the same. `compare` compares two things while `compareTo` is called on the instance of one thing to compare it with another. I'm mentioning it in the last line of my question already. Anyways, thanks for linking this answer here. I read it before posting this question but its good to have it linked.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak: You are absolutely right, the culprit is lambdas. But I wish to understand the concept in light of lambdas. Otherwise this question doesn't arise in the first place, for me.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand why you expect it to fail. And the exact term is 'type inference', not lambdas.

Comment: @RahulSharma: I don't expect it to fail per se, but I don't get how it works! The way I see, the two methods being passed are quite different.

Comment: Check [this](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/lang/Integer.java#Integer.compareTo%28java.lang.Integer%29) out. The implementation of compareTo is just a call to the static compare method, therefore the results for the two methods are the same. Hope this helps.

Comment: @RahulSharma: Even if its just a wrapper over the same method, the call is different. I think I'm not yet precisely able to understand my problem. There's something that lambdas do that I don't know of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using two types of [method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html). The first is a [reference to a static method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html#static). The second is a [reference to a type instance method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html#type). After autoboxing, they both share the same functional signature of `(Integer, Integer) -> int`.

Since method references are just syntactical sugar for lambdas, here's how they would translate into lambdas:

`Integer::compare` evaluates to

```
(int left, int right) -> Integer.compare(left, right)
```

`Integer::compareTo` evaluates to

```
(Integer left, Integer right) -> left.compareTo(right)
```

Comment: Your answer clarifies the point partly. I don't understand how can two methods having different signature be accepted to produce same effect on the data? Will read autoboxing before commenting further on your answer.

Comment: Wish I could up-vote twice. Thank you for your explanation. Your answer makes it clear.

Answer (score 1):

```
Collections.sort(listOfInts, Integer::compare);
```

is equivalent to this code in older Java:

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
        return Integer.compare(o1, o2);
    }
});
```

While

```
Collections.sort(listOfInts, Integer::compareTo);
```

is equivalent to

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
        return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
});
```

There is no overloading here. `sort` method requires the second argument to be a `Comparator`. It is just Java 8 lambdas that hide it from you.

Comment: Your answer makes sense to me. If possible for you, could you elaborate how the lambdas *actually* hide it? No prob if you can't.

Comment: @displayName They hide it exactly as shown above. You type `Integer::compare` but it actually creates a `new Comparator()` whose `compareTo(Integer o1, Integer o2)` method's implementation is `return Integer.compare(o1, o2);`