# CompareTo() and compare() methods of comparator and comparable

Tags: java, comparator

From the below code I am not understanding two things:

1. The `CompareTo()` and `Compare()` methods return `int`, but how does this affect the sorting?
2. The method returns `this.name.compareTo(d.name)`. What is present in `this.name`?

Please explain elaborately.

```
import java.util.*;

class Dog implements Comparator<Dog>, Comparable<Dog>{
   private String name;
   private int age;
   Dog(){
   }

   Dog(String n, int a){
      name = n;
      age = a;
   }

   public String getDogName(){
      return name;
   }

   public int getDogAge(){
      return age;
   }

   // Overriding the compareTo method
   public int compareTo(Dog d){
      return (this.name).compareTo(d.name);
   }

   // Overriding the compare method to sort the age 
   public int compare(Dog d, Dog d1){
      return d.age - d1.age;
   }
}

public class Example{

   public static void main(String args[]){
      // Takes a list o Dog objects
      List<Dog> list = new ArrayList<Dog>();

      list.add(new Dog("Shaggy",3));
      list.add(new Dog("Lacy",2));
      list.add(new Dog("Roger",10));
      list.add(new Dog("Tommy",4));
      list.add(new Dog("Tammy",1));
      Collections.sort(list);// Sorts the array list

      for(Dog a: list)//printing the sorted list of names
         System.out.print(a.getDogName() + ", ");

      // Sorts the array list using comparator
      Collections.sort(list, new Dog());
      System.out.println(" ");
      for(Dog a: list)//printing the sorted list of ages
         System.out.print(a.getDogName() +"  : "+
         a.getDogAge() + ", ");
   }
}
```

Comment: Whatever you're doing, it's nonsensical.  `Dog` should _not_ implement `Comparator<Dog>`; you should have a separate class (probably anonymous) implementing `Comparator<Dog>`.  In the meantime, what do you expect `this.name` to be?  It's the name of this dog, being compared to another dog.

Comment: For `compare`, if the dog's ages are the same, they're equal. Otherwise, if the first dog is older, it'll return a positive number, second dog, negative number.

Comment: @louis I dint get u sorry

Comment: A dog would implement Animal (Dog is a type of Animal), not a Comparator (Dog is not a type of Comparator)

Answer (score 1):

As you probably guessed, *compare* and *compareTo* are used to compare two objects.

**How it works**

`compare(a, b)` compares objects a and b. If the returned value is < 0, then a is lower than b. If it is 0, both objects are equal. If it is superior to 0, a is greater than b.

`a.compareTo(b)` also compares objects a and b. The return value works the same way as for `compare`. However, when calling it you have to be careful that a is not null, else it throws a NullPointerException.

**When to use it**

If your class only need one comparison scheme, then only using `compareTo` is fine.

However, if you need to sort `Dog` in several ways, for example at one time you want to sort them by age and another time by name, this is where `Comparator` becomes handy. You can just create two `Comparator<Dog>`, one which sorts by age and the other by name. When calling a method like sort, you provide as argument the comparator you want to use in order to get the sorting you want.

**Relative to your question**

The keyword `this` refers to the current Dog instance. So, `this.name` is the name of the current `Dog` instance.

Answer (score 0):

CompareTo() is used to define the 'natural order' of the objects and creates an int to determine which object is 'greater' than the other and implements Comparable.

```
a.compareTo(b)<0    //same as a<b     
a.compareTo(b)>0    //same as a>b
a.compareTo(b)==0   //same as a==b
a.compareTo(b)!=0   //same as a!=b
a.compareTo(b)<=0   //same as a<=b
a.compareTo(b)>=0   //same as a>=b
```

As for how it will sort differently than compare() is entirely up to how you implement the compareTo().

Heres an example on how assuming phoneNumber has 3 fields: **areaCode**, **prefix**, **lineNumber**:

```
    public  int compareTo(PhoneNumber pn){  
                //  Compare area codes  
            if  (areaCode< pn.areaCode) {   
                return -1;  
            }   
            if  (areaCode > pn.areaCode){   
                    return 1;   
            }   
            //  Area codes are equal, compare prefixes  
            if  (prefix < pn.prefix){   
                    return -1;  
            }   
            if  (prefix > pn.prefix){   
                    return 1;   
            }   
            //  Area codes and prefixes are equal, compare line numbers 
            if  (lineNumber < pn.lineNumber){   
                    return -1;  
            }   
            if  (lineNumber > pn.lineNumber){   
                    return  1;  
            }   
            return  0;  //  All fields  are equal   
            }
```

While compare() takes two objects and compares the values between their fields, and implements Comparator

```
compare(a,b)<0    //same as a<b     
compare(a,b)>0    //same as a>b
compare(a,b)==0   //same as a==b
compare(a,b)!=0   //same as a!=b
compare(a,b)<=0   //same as a<=b
compare(a,b)>=0   //same as a>=b
```

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420223/what-is-the-difference-between-compare-and-compareto) answer has a much more elaborate and articulate explanation on comparator and comparable.