# TreeMap Comparator not giving the order expected?

Tags: java, list, entity, comparator, treemap

I am attempting to create a `TreeMap` with the following Format:

```
TreeMap<Kenel, List<Dog>> treeMapOfKennelsAndDogs;
```

Each entry is a `Kennel` object with an attached list of `Dogs`. I want to compare each Kennel by the *oldest Dog in each* and order accordingly.

However the order of the `treeMap` is not what I am expecting, it seems that when a Kennel has a Dog List of *size 1* in the list then the ordering is incorrect.

Below is my code to find the oldest Dog related to each Kennel, and also my comparator logic.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "KENNEL")
public class Kennel {

    //other fields 

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "KENNEL_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", updatable = true, insertable = true)
    private List<Dog> dogList;

     public DateTime getOldestDogInList() {
        if (dogList.size() == 0) {
            return null; }

        Dog dog= dogList.get(0);
        for (int i = 1; i < dogList.size(); i++) {
            dog d = dogList.get(i);
            if (d.getCreated().isBefore(dog.getCreated())) {
                dog = d;
            }
        }
        return dog.getCreated();
    }
```

Comparator logic in service class:

```
    Comparator<Kennel> oldestDog = new Comparator<Kennel>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Kennel k1, Kennel k2) {

            int result = k1.getOldestDogInList().compareTo(k2.getOldestDogInList());

            return result;
        }
    };

  TreeMap<Kennel, List<Dog>> treeMapOfKennelsAndDogs = new TreeMap<>(oldestDog);
```

Is there an error in code that would cause the incorrect ordering in the TreeMap?

Comment: If a `Kenel` already contains a `List<Dog>` member, why do you need a `TreeMap<Kenel, List<Dog>>`? You can use a `TreeSet<Kenel>` instead.

Comment: What is the actual sorting?

Comment: Kennels that have dogs that are younger than others are actually earlier in the Map?

Comment: That makes sense, because when you compare the dates, the earliest comes first.

Comment: I don't know what you mean? surely the oldest should be first in the treemap?

Comment: Just because x’s oldest dog is older than y’s doesn’t preclude that x could also have dogs younger than y’s. That’s no contradiction. The lists don’t have a total order, i.e. sorting them by youngest dog can lead to an entirely different order than sorting them by oldest.

Answer (score 0):

> Comparator logic in service class:

**TreeSet** don't know about your service classes. It knows only about Generic type inside.

**1st sollution:**

Comparator logic should be in a class that will be sorted in `TreeSet`. You should implement `Comparator` and ovverade `compare` method in `Kennel` class.

**2nd sollution:**

Set `Comparator` when create `TreeMap`.

```
TreeMap<Kenel, List<Dog>> treemap = new TreeMap<Kenel, List<Dog>>(new Comparator<Kenel>() {
    public int compare(Kennel k1, Kennel k2) {
        int result = k1.getOldestDogInList().compareTo(k2.getOldestDogInList());
        return result;
    }
});
```

Related question: [What is the difference between compare() and compareTo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420223/what-is-the-difference-between-compare-and-compareto)

Comment: I cannot alter this Kennel class as it is legacy code. This is why I am taking the approach that I am currently?

Comment: @java123999, make `Adapter pattern`: create new class that extends `Kennel`, implements `Comparator`. You will not succeed in your TreeMap autosorting without doing implementing `Comparator`

Comment: @java123999, I edited my question. I added solution with setting `Comparator` dynamically

Answer (score 0):

1. Compare logic of `Map<K, V>` keys should not depend on `V` class.
2. Do you modify keys instances after inserting in `Map`?  If yes - it is a problem. Equality check is only on insetion*.
3. The ordering maintained by a tree map, like any sorted map, and whether or not an explicit comparator is provided, must be consistent with equals. (From javadoc)