# Why String implements Comparable and not Comparator interface

Tags: java, string, comparator, comparable

This question was asked in an interview. The question was why `Strin`g and other wrapper classes implement `Comparable` instead of `Comparator` interface. I tried to explain that `Comparator` is basically to provide customized sorting and `Comparable` is for default natural sorting order. Also from design principle perspective, `Comparable` is tightly coupled and `Comparator` is loosely coupled. However, I could not clarify why `String` implemented `Comparable` instead of `Comparator`.

Comment: Other semi-duplicates: "[When should a class be Comparable and/or Comparator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440134)" and "[What is the difference between compare() and compareTo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420223)".  Unfortunately, there's no canonical dup-target question for this... just a handful of moderately upvoted mutual duplicates.

Answer (score 4):

Strings implement `Comparable` because they are things that *can be compared*. In general, things that implement `Comparable` tend to have a natural ordering, like you mentioned.

A `Comparator` is a way of comparing things. When you make a Comparator, you're defining a method with which to compare things. You can make many Comparators on a given type to compare things in different ways.

Comment: I mentioned something about natural ordering above. Yes, but I think we can easily modify this ordering by overriding the compareTo() method. I mean this varies from implementation to implementation . It's not specific to Comparable or Comparator. String is a mutable class and implemented in such a way that it always gives you natural order sort.

Comment: You can modify the ordering by overriding compareTo, but for each class implementing Comparable you can only have one defined ordering, because you have to pick a particular way to write compareTo. However, you can make several Comparators that compare objects of a particular class, each of which can define different orderings. Check out the other comparable vs comparator questions for more info as well.