# compare objects doesnt work

Tags: java, oop, compare

I'm trying to compare the names of objects of my own class Person so I can sort an ArrayList. I followed what my teacher did but can't seem to get why it doesn't work.

```
import java.util.*;

public class SortName implements Comparable<Person>{
    public int compare(Person p1, Person p2){
        return p1.getName().compareTo(p2.getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the output? any error you got?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compare() method is correct, BUT you’re using the wrong interface. Implement Comparator, not Comparable. They’re easy to mix up.

```
import java.util.*;

public class SortName implements Comparator<Person>{
    public int compare(Person p1, Person p2){
        return p1.getName().compareTo(p2.getName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It should be `Comparator` interface. `Comparator` interface has `compare()` method not `Comparable`.

```
public class SortName implements Comparator<Person>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try it with `compareTo()` method:

```
import java.util.*;

public class SortName implements Comparable<Person>{
    public int compareTo(Person p2){
        return this.getName().compareTo(p2.getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: Its incorrect. compareTo() method of Comparable has does accept two arguments, Its compareTo(Object obj)

Answer (score 1):

Referring to [What is the difference between compare() and compareTo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420223/what-is-the-difference-between-compare-and-compareto)

[Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface let you override its `int compare(Object o1, Object o2)` method. 
Implementing this interface helps you to sort your inbuilt data structure or even a custom defined data data structure.

[Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface lets you override its `int compareTo(Object o)` method.
Example: `(x.compareTo(y)==0) == (x.equals(y))`