# My class does not override abstract method compareTo

Tags: java, abstract-class, compareto

My class details attributes of restaurants downtown, said attributes being x/y locations and rank. The problem is, whenever I run the program It throws an error, saying that non-abstract class "Downtown" does not override abstract method "compareTo". I cannot make this class abstract because I need to initialise the object outside this block of code.  Where does my program go wrong? Is there a problem with my compareTo implementation? Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

```
public class Downtown implements Comparable<Downtown> {//Throws error on this line
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int rank;

    public Downtown(int x, int y, int rank) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.rank = rank;
    }
    //Appropriate setters and getters for x , y and rank
    public int getX() {
         return x;
    }
    public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
    }
    public int getY() {
    return y;
    }
    public void setY(int y) {
    this.y = y;
    }
    public int getRank() {
    return rank;
    }
    public void setRank(int rank) {
    this.rank = rank;
    }   

    public int compareTo(Downtown p1, Downtown p2)//Actual comparison
    {
        // This is so that the sort goes x first, y second and rank last

        // First by x- stop if this gives a result.
        int xResult = Integer.compare(p1.getX(),p1.getX());
        if (xResult != 0)
        {
            return xResult;
        }

        // Next by y
        int yResult = Integer.compare(p1.getY(),p2.getY());
        if (yResult != 0)
        {
            return yResult;
        }

        // Finally by rank
        return Integer.compare(p1.getRank(),p2.getRank());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "["+x+' '+y+' '+rank+' '+"]";
    }
```

Comment: `compareTo` only takes one parameter: `public int compareTo(Downtown p2)`. It's supposed to compare `this` with `p2`.

Comment: Signature of compareTo() is wrong. Refer to https://dzone.com/articles/java-comparable-interface-in-five-minutes for details.

Comment: Your `compareTo` function actually takes 3 `Downtown` objects: `p1`, `p2,` and `this`.   This is not the correct signature for `compareTo`.

Comment: Tip: Use the `@Override` annotation on methods that should be overrides.  You'll get a compiler error if the method signature is wrong.

Comment: [Java : Comparable vs Comparator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4108604), [What is the difference between compare() and compareTo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/420223)

Comment: as Pshemo pointed out if you want to compare value of two object then use Comparator<T> interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `compareTo` method should compare the *current* object (`this`) to just *one* other.  It shouldn't have *two* parameters for comparison.  You could write your method like this.

```
public int compareTo(Downtown p2)//Actual comparison
{
    // This is so that the sort goes x first, y second and rank last

    // First by x- stop if this gives a result.
    int xResult = Integer.compare(getX(),p2.getX());
    if (xResult != 0)
    {
        return xResult;
    }

    // Next by y
    int yResult = Integer.compare(getY(),p2.getY());
    if (yResult != 0)
    {
        return yResult;
    }

    // Finally by rank
    return Integer.compare(getRank(),p2.getRank());
}
```

Notice how I've replace all the calls on `p1` to calls on the current object.

Answer (score 2):

Java's `Comparable<T>` interface defines `compareTo` method as follows:

```
int compareTo(T o);
```

This means that the method must take one parameter; the other parameter is the object itself, i.e. `this`. You need to implement this one-argument method in place of your two-argument method to fix this problem.

Compiler will help you figure out issues like this by using [`@Override` annotation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/predefined.html) on your method:

```
@Override // Issues an error
public int compareTo(Downtown p1, Downtown p2)

@Override // Compiles fine
public int compareTo(Downtown other)
```