# Should I use Comparator or Comparable when trying to use a Priority Queue with this generic class?

Tags: java, comparison, priority-queue

When trying to give generic objects priority in a Priority Queue what can I use to compare them? Can I define and use an overridden CompareTo method from the Comparable interface or an overridden Compare method from the Comparator interface? Or could I use one or the other? Thanks

Here are the instance variables, constructor of the class, and the current compareTo method.

```
private LocalTime scheduledTime; //the scheduled time of the flight
private Event.EventType eventType; //the event type of the flight (arrival or departure)
private String identifier;  // the identifier of the flight
private LocalTime actualTime; //the actual time the flight uses a runway
private Runway runwayUsed; //the runway the flight used to arrive or depart
private int reserveTime; // time the flight uses to reserve a runway 
private LocalTime runwayAvailableTime;


/**
 * Constructor
 * @param scheduledTime the scheduled time of the flight
 * @param eventType the event of the flight (arrival or departure)
 * @param identifier the identifier of the flight
 */
protected Flight(String scheduledTime, String eventType, String identifier) {


    this.scheduledTime = LocalTime.parse(scheduledTime);
    this.eventType = EventType.valueOf(eventType);
    this.identifier = identifier;
    this.actualTime = null;
    this.runwayUsed = null;

} 

//Here is the compareTo method I am currently using. Should I use compare //from the Comparator interface instead?
@Override
public int compareTo(Event otherFlight) {

    Event tmpFlight = (Event) otherFlight;


        if(this.scheduledTime.compareTo(tempFlight.getScheduledTime()) == 0) {
        if(this.eventType.compareTo(tempFlight.getEvent()) == 0){
            return 0;
        } 
        else if(this.eventType.compareTo(tempFlight.getEvent()) > 0){
            return 1;
        } 
        else {
            return -1;
        } 
    } 
    else if(this.scheduledTime.compareTo(tempFlight.getScheduledTime()) < 0) {
        return -1;
    } 
    else {
        return 1;
    }  }
```

Comment: You can use either. It's your choice what you implement...

Comment: Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420223/what-is-the-difference-between-compare-and-compareto before making a decision, they are not same.

Comment: Which should I use in the case above?

Comment: How is your `Flight` class declared? Why do you have `compareTo(Event)` instead of `compareTo(Flight)`?

Comment: Based on the information that Prabin Paudel posted, I believe the way in which I would like to compare the Flight objects is not in 'natural order', so I should use the compare method of the Comparator interface, correct?

Comment: @ Ernest Kiwele it is defined as: public class Flight implements Event, Comparable<Event>, Cloneable{

Comment: As of Java 8, you don’t need to write a method.  You can just use `new PriorityQueue<Event>(Comparator.comparing(Event::getScheduledTime).thenComparing(Event::getEventType))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already have implemented `compareTo`, you have `Comparable` `Flight` or `Event` instances.

That means you're set to use it with `Comparable` objects. All of the below should work:

```
Queue<Event> eventQueue = new PriorityQueue<>();
eventQueue.add(new Flight(scheduledTime, eventType, identifier));
```

Or:

```
List<Flight> flightList = Arrays.asList(new Flight(scheduledTime, 
                           eventType, identifier));
Queue<Flight> flightQueue = new PriorityQueue<>(flightList);
```

Or:

```
List<Event> eventList = ...;
Queue<Event> eventQueue = new PriorityQueue<>(eventList);
```

The `PiorityQueue` class should be able to handle the priority according to the order dictated by your `compareTo` ordering.

**Note:** if your `List<Event>` has objects of other classes that implement `Event`, then you must make sure that those other classes also have `compareTo(Event otherFlight)`. Otherwise, the priority queue may raise exceptions at runtime.

The best option may be to just declare `Flight` as implementing `Comparable<Flight>` and instantiate a `PriorityQueue<Flight>` queue.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Because I was not comparing by 'natural order' I thought that I had to implement the Comparator interface and use the compare method. Thank you for letting me know that I can use the compareTo method of the Comparable interface when using a Priority Queue of Flight or Event objects.